# Symfony 4.4: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am receiving the following error when attempting to force the database:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 128: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver In Exception.php line 18: could not find driver In PDOConnection.php line 40: could not find driver
```

Here is the code for my `php.ini` file:

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=oci8_19  ; Use with Oracle Database 19 Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

Additionally, here is the code for my env file and env local:

```
evn - DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/food_cloud 
evn local - 'DATABASE_URL' => 'mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/food_cloud',
```

None of the solutions on this site have worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using docker by any chance, cause you can try installing the extension with the command:

```bash
docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

If you are not in docker, try installing php-mysql see if it works after:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mysql (just replace 8.0 with your php version)
```